# Replace content in DataTables column based on word

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

How can I replace the value of a cell in a column in DataTables, based on the word in the cell. For example, if the word is "Active", the word will be in green. If the word is "Inactive" it will be in red. Currently I can only highlight all words within the same column, but not target a column based on the word or even first letter.

DataTables code:

```
$('#dataTables-example').dataTable( {
        "ajax": 'publishers.txt',
        "createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {
        if ( data[3].replace(/[\A,]/, '')) {
            $('td', row).eq(3).addClass('highlight');
        }
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
td.highlight {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in Datatables reference docs:

```
"columnDefs": [ {
            "targets": 3,
            "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
              if ( cellData == "Active" ) {
                $(td).css('color', 'green')
              }
              if ( cellData == "Inactive") {
                $(td).css('color', 'red')
              }
            }
} ]
```